# Displaying raw data URL on a custom content type

Tags: php, html, drupal

I have created by own "Content Type" called "test" in Drupal 7 with the field "Homepage" [field_homepage]. I have also created and am using my own theme. In this theme I have created a template for this "test" content type called node--test.tpl.php

```
<a href="<?php print render($content['field_homepage']); ?>" target="_blank">Homepage</a>
```

The only problem is that when this is printed out, drupal adds extra span styling as follows.

```
<div class="field field-name-field-homepage field-type-text field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">my homepage</div></div></div>
```

Now this proves problematic as my link will not be displayed properly.

What is the solution to this? I heard that maybe I could override field.tpl.php however there is performance issues. I thought this would be a common and simple task.

Thanks.

Comment: [Solved] Used the link module, http://drupal.org/project/link